# Checking if EditText is empty

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext

I'm just trying to check if EditText is empty or not...
I have:

```
EditText a, b, c;
double A, B, C;
```

And also:

```
a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);
b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b);
c = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.c);
```

And of course:

```
if (a.getText().length() == 0)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Ax^2 Cannot Be Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
else {
    A = Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString());

    if (b.getText().length() == 0)
        B = 0;
    else
        B = Double.parseDouble(b.getText().toString());

    if (c.getText().length() == 0)
        C = 0;
    else
        C = Double.parseDouble(c.getText().toString());

    Intent act = new Intent(this, PopupResult.class);
    act.putExtra("A", A);
    act.putExtra("B", B);
    act.putExtra("C", C);
    startActivity(act);
}
```

It's really weird because the 1st `if` (the one with the `a`) works.
Help Please!
If the 1st `EditText` is empty, so there is a Toast, just like I wanted. But if the 2nd or the 3rd `EditText` are empty, the app crashes.
I want to set `B` and `C` to 0 if the fields are empty.

Comment: You want to check if all three are empty or not at a single shot?

Comment: @Gautham No, I'm trying to check each separately

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Please explain how you want it to work and how it currently works

Comment: Are you overriting your EditTexts with Strings?

Comment: @AnDrOiD Checkout my answer.

Comment: @AnDrOiD post the stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

You should use `toString()` function. Also to avoid white space from both ends use `b.getText().toString().trim()`

```
if (b.getText().toString().length() <= 0)
    B = 0;
else
    B = Double.parseDouble(b.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out below code to check for the Empty `EditText`

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(b.getText().toString.trim())
 {
      B = 0;
  }else
   {
      B = Double.parseDouble(b.getText().toString());
  }

  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(c.getText().toString.trim())
    C = 0;
  else
    C = Double.parseDouble(c.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

EditText `.getText()` method returns an Editable object try using `getText().toString().length()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
if(a.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""){
//your comment
}
if(b.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""){
//your comment
}
if(c.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""){
//your comment
}
```

Comment: @AnDrOiD Have tried with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(b.getText())
```

`public static boolean isEmpty (CharSequence str)`

```
Added in API level 1
Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

Parameters
str the string to be examined
Returns
true if str is null or zero length
```

So you can do as below

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(a.getText().toString()) // return true if length is 0 or null
{
     Toast.makeText(this, "Ax^2 Cannot Be Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else 
{
      A = Double.parseDouble(a.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: But I don't have any problem with `A`

Comment: @AnDrOiD the exception could also be bcoz you din't initialize properly the edittexts. How do you know its initialized properly. post stacktrace. could also be a that you din't enter a valid double value